# How to replace () with RegEx using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is my RegEx:

```
console.log(test.replace(/0098/g, ")").replace(/[()]/g, ''));
```

How can I replace only `()` if exists?

My code replace now all bridgets.
I want to replace only where is exists `()`.

Like my example:

```
var test = "(test1234) - test948 () usi27361() 928372da";
```

New string: `(test1234) - test948  usi27361 928372da`

Comment: I think you are looking to escape those characters. Maybe > `\(\)`

Comment: [()] matches both characters even when they are 'alone'. You want to match the string '()' - That's what Yosef's answer below does.

Comment: To rephase @PoulBak comment above (not incorrect, just rephrasing it) - `[xyz]` - means match any *one* of the characters in the `[]` - it's the equivalent of `x or y or z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = "(test1234) - test948 () usi27361() 928372da";
console.log(str.replace(/\(\)/g, ""));
```